# How to tell Agda that property always holds in branch of `if`?

Tags: agda

Say I want to have a `Digit` type that is a refinement of `Char` to only digits:

```
open import Data.Bool using (Bool; true; if_then_else_)
open import Data.Char using (Char; isDigit)
open import Data.Maybe using (Maybe; just; nothing)

data IsTrue : Bool → Set where
  is-true : IsTrue true

data IsDigit (c : Char) : Set where
  is-digit : {p : IsTrue (isDigit c)} → IsDigit c

data Digit : Set where
  digit : (c : Char) → {p : IsDigit c} → Digit
```

I can then construct, e.g., the `Digit` for `'0'` like so (although the obvious parameters that I seem to need to pass are frustrating):

```
0-digit : Digit
0-digit = digit '0' {is-digit {_} {is-true}}
```

However, if I want a function that takes an arbitrary `Char` and returns `Maybe Digit`, I can't seem to communicate to Agda that in the `then` branch, `isDigit c` always holds. How do I make this visible to Agda?

In some languages, this would be a form of flow typing, but if I understand correctly, Agda only has "flow typing" when pattern-matching on constructors. It *does* compile if I exhaustively match on `'0', '1', ... '9'`, but that's tedious and seems unfortunate.

```
maybeFromChar : Char → Maybe Digit
maybeFromChar c =
  if isDigit c
    then just (digit c {is-digit {c} {is-true}})
    else nothing
```

```
.../Foo.agda:20,39-46
true != isDigit c of type Bool
when checking that the expression is-true has type
IsTrue (isDigit c)
```

(Suggestions for improvements to the way I'm modeling `Digit` are welcome as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`inspect`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/README.Inspect.html) idiom to remember the match (you'll need to add `false` to the import list of `Data.Bool`):

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

maybeFromChar : Char → Maybe Digit
maybeFromChar c with isDigit c | inspect isDigit c
... | true  | [ eq ] = just (digit c {is-digit {c} {subst IsTrue (sym eq) is-true}})
... | _     | _      = nothing
```

You can also use the dependent version of `if_then_else_` a.k.a. the eliminator of `Bool`:

```
open import Function
open import Data.Maybe as Maybe

elimBool : ∀ {π} → (P : Bool → Set π) → P true → P false → ∀ b → P b
elimBool P t f true  = t
elimBool P t f false = f

maybeFromChar' : Char → Maybe Digit
maybeFromChar' c =
  Maybe.map (λ p -> digit c {is-digit {_} {p}}) $
    elimBool (Maybe ∘ IsTrue) (just is-true) nothing (isDigit c)
```

Comment: Thanks! `inspect` is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. I also realized `IsDigit c = IsTrue (isDigit c)` is a simpler representation than using a full datatype.